# How to apply correct classname for active NavLink react-router-dom v6?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I try to style my active nav link but I cant do this, the link always has class `"flights-table-daylink active-Btn"`.

This is my code, I watched this in tutorial from good guy but in my project this does not work.

[codesandbox.io/s/style-navllink-sksgrg?file=/src/App.js](https://codesandbox.io/s/style-navllink-sksgrg?file=/src/App.js)

```
const setActive = ({ isActive }) =>
  isActive ? "flights-table-daylink active-Btn" : "flights-table-daylink";

<NavLink to="/departure" className={setActive}>
  <span>1</span>
</NavLink>
```

Comment: According to the [React Router docs](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/nav-link#classname) this is valid code. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: No i dont have any error and if i click in link and it is active it have "flights-table-daylink active-Btn"  and if it is not active it have "flights-table-daylink active-Btn"

Comment: so, what the thing is not work for you?

Comment: I want toggle my classNames, and change style for links but if i use this way const setActive = ({ isActive }) => isActive ? 'flights-table-daylink active-Btn' : 'flights-table-daylink'; <NavLink className={setActive}> <span>1</span> </NavLink> i always have in my link class 'flights-table-daylink active-Btn' and if i choose link i have + 'flights-table-daylink active-Btn active'

Comment: Other than missing a link target, e.g. the `to` prop, I see no issue with this code. See if you can create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces the issue you describe that we can inspect live.

Comment: i dont know how good i need to Do this but i did do it like this 
https://codesandbox.io/s/style-navllink-sksgrg?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Sorry, you should have tagged me in the comment and I could have seen this earlier. The code in your sandbox appears to correctly apply the `"active-btn"` classname. It doesn't reproduce the issue you describe. https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-apply-correct-classname-for-active-navlink-react-router-dom-v6-xk8knj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't provide a **to** **prop** to a **NavLink** **component** in React Router, it will not be able to determine whether the current route matches the link's destination. The className prop has been set to the **setActive** **function**, which will return a different class name based on the **isActive** **property**.

When you provide a **to** **prop** to a **NavLink**, React Router will compare the current URL with the destination URL specified in the **to** **prop**. If the current URL matches the to prop of the NavLink, the **isActive** property will be **true**, and the **active-Btn** class will be applied to the NavLink. Otherwise, the **isActive** property will be **false**, and only the **flights-table-daylink** class will be applied.

```
const setActive = ({ isActive }) =>
  isActive ? "flights-table-daylink active-Btn" : "flights-table-daylink";

 <NavLink to={"/"} className={setActive}>
   <span>1</span>
 </NavLink>
```

Now everything will work exactly as you expected.